# Eevee Artistic style outlines for 3d object SHADER

Tags: eevee-render-engine, npr

Im trying to go for a look like this[image]

The lines are what im trying to accomplish.
The skuffs, the break in perfection, the drawn look.

Comment: Im also looking for a way to do it in real time. not a post effect like "Freestyle"

Comment: You could try a Line Art Modifier (add a Grease Pencil stroke, delete the points, add modifier and point it to the collection containing your mesh), but it's a relatively new feature and still rather slow.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Imma give that a shot, that should do the trick, thank you.

Comment: i'm also looking to replicate 2D style like this in 3D. this has been made fairly well with ARC SYSTEMS WORKS games. Looking at dragon ball fighter Z and guilty gear i'm all for it.
looking at the presentation of technical artist Junya C Motomura at GDC 2015, they achieve to translate their historical 2D character in 3D with a combinaison of square UV mapping with UV outline/manually adjusted normal and a good cell shader with illumination map. that's said it takes a huge amount of time and fine tuning. thanks to Motomura speech, ***The Guilty Gear Style*** In Blender have been debunked by som

Answer (score 0):

There's a free add-on that does this in one click- the outlines anyway- https://felineentity.gumroad.com/l/ZmTIT
Everything else you're asking about is a different question